# Selecting row where field = value error

Tags: php, joomla

Can you explain me why my code isnt working? Ive been thinking about it for a while and I cant find it. obviously I want to print some columns from rows where column F1 is equal to user's username.

```
$db = JFactory::getDBO();
$user = JFactory::getUser();

$query = "SELECT * FROM qwozh_visforms_1 WHERE F1 = ".$user->username;

$db->setQuery($query);
$result = $db->query();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_object($result))
{
  print $row->F1;
}
```

It works when I remove condition from select command and I cant figure out how to make it work with it

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM qwozh_visforms_1";
```

Now Im getting this error:

> UNKNOWN COLUMN 'ADMIN' IN 'WHERE CLAUSE' SQL=SELECT * FROM
>   QWOZH_VISFORMS_1 WHERE F1 = ADMIN RETURN TO PREVIOUS PAGE

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All it takes if a quick read of the Joomla documentation. The following is the same as your query but making full use of Joomla's up to date database class:

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$user = JFactory::getUser();

$query = $db->getQuery(true);    
$query->select(array('*'))
      ->from($db->quoteName('#__visforms_1'))
      ->where($db->quoteName('F1') . ' = '. $db->quote($user->username));     
$db->setQuery($query);

$results = $db->loadObjectList();


// Display the results
foreach($results as $result){
    // echo what you want here
}
```

Note, I've used the prefix `#__` rather than manually defining `qwozh`, assuming your table belong to a Joomla extension.

Comment: This one is not working, it says: UNKNOWN COLUMN '*' IN 'FIELD LIST' SQL=SELECT `*` FROM `QWOZH_VISFORMS_1` WHERE `F1` = 'ADMIN'
RETURN TO PREVIOUS PAGE

Comment: @tnqm - oops. I've updated the code. It will work now.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap the name in quotes:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM qwozh_visforms_1 WHERE F1 = '".$user->username . "'";
```

As pointed out in the comments my answer has a pretty bad quality, you may want to look at [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php), expecially using [`bindParam`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php), which takes care of quotes for you and protects you agains SQL injection attacks.

Unfortunately I cannot suggest you Joomla based approach since I never used it, somebody else can suggest you a more appropriate solution.

Comment: If you're not going to suggest binding a value in a prepared statement, you should at least suggest the use of `mysql_escape_string()` (depreciated).

Comment: @myninjaname you are right, my bad, my Joomla knowledge is very bad and I didn't know if there's something specific for it or to suggest prepared statements.

Comment: Thanks! This is very weird syntax, in phpmyadmin, its recommending me to wrap the database name in quotes, what causes syntax error. But for some reason its not needed there, although its needed at comparation. Very weird.

Answer (score 0):

I know PHP and MySQL, but not Joomla. But the problem is that your username needs to be quoted because it is probably a string.

Try this:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM qwozh_visforms_1 WHERE F1 = '{$user->username}'";
```

or

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM qwozh_visforms_1 WHERE F1 = ".$db->quote($user->username);
```